# How to take and save 20 photo in one second using objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, image-processing, avcapturesession

I am creating one photo capture app in which user can take up to 20 photo in one second.
I have already try the AVCam Sample code of apple but it is don't allow to take still Image at 20 FPS.

Is there any other way to take photo at this rate.

Answer (score 0):

see this Demo..[Photo Picker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196)

in this demo just check or refer these two classes..

1. [MyViewController.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Listings/MyViewController_m.html) and
2. [OverlayViewController.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Listings/OverlayViewController_m.html)

in `OverlayViewController.m` class  in `timedTakePhoto` method just set timer with your requirement like bellow..

```
- (IBAction)timedTakePhoto:(id)sender
{
    // these controls can't be used until the photo has been taken
    self.cancelButton.enabled = NO;
    self.takePictureButton.enabled = NO;
    self.timedButton.enabled = NO;
    self.startStopButton.enabled = NO;

    if (self.cameraTimer != nil)
        [self.cameraTimer invalidate];
    _cameraTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(timedPhotoFire:)
                                                 userInfo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kOneShot]
                                                  repeats:YES];
     // set time with your requirement above     

    // start the timer to sound off a tick every 1 second (sound effect before a timed picture is taken)
    if (self.tickTimer != nil)
        [self.tickTimer invalidate];
    _tickTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(tickFire:)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];
}
```

may you can get idea from this and also use this demo for your requirement..

i hope this help you...

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is still not allow me to take photo at 20 FPS. it also take more time for each image.

Comment: you set timeinterval with 0.05 or something?? and also try with your custom code dude...

Comment: Thanks budy, but I have also try that but it is not capable to take photo at that time interval